Event listener for Keycloak Quarkus
I am trying to create an event listener for Keycloak Quarkus. If I use mnv package, there are many Keycloak classes missing in the class loader. So after selecting the created listener in Keycloak, it cannot handle any event because the bean is not injected and the object is null.
Pice of code that throws NPE:
@ApplicationScoped
@NoArgsConstructor
public class KeycloakEventListenerProviderFactory implements EventListenerProviderFactory {

    @Inject
    KeycloakEventListener keycloakEventListener;

    @Override
    public EventListenerProvider create(KeycloakSession keycloakSession) {
        keycloakEventListener.setSession(keycloakSession);
        return keycloakEventListener;
    }
    ...
}

build warnings:
[io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanArchives] Failed to index org.keycloak.events.EventListenerProviderFactory: Class does not exist in ClassLoader QuarkusClassLoader:Deployment Class Loader: PROD for keycloak-user-listener-1.0-SNAPSHOT@30f929ff
[io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanArchives] Failed to index org.keycloak.events.EventListenerProvider: Class does not exist in ClassLoader QuarkusClassLoader:Deployment Class Loader: PROD for keycloak-user-listener-1.0-SNAPSHOT@30f929ff
[io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanArchives] Failed to index org.keycloak.models.KeycloakSession: Class does not exist in ClassLoader QuarkusClassLoader:Deployment Class Loader: PROD for keycloak-user-listener-1.0-SNAPSHOT@30f929ff

Running app locally with REST endpoint that uses KeycloakEventListenerProviderFactory create() method. Works well
Run listener in Keycloak without CDI using new operator. So its worked fine.
Adding plugin below so nothing changed
<groupId>org.jboss.jandex</groupId>
<artifactId>jandex-maven-plugin</artifactId>

